# overlay colors on the view

Tags: android, kotlin, background, overlay

I am facing a specific issue of view background overlay. I did simple example project to show my problem
i have 2 view with the same size. Also both view have background - GradientDrawable with corner radius.
xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="100dp">
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

And my mainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val view1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.view_1)
        val view2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.view_2)
        val bg1 = GradientDrawable().apply {
            setColor(Color.BLUE)
            cornerRadius = 20.toPxF()
        }
        val bg2 = GradientDrawable().apply {
            setColor(Color.RED)
            cornerRadius = 20.toPxF()

        }
        view1.background = bg1
        view2.background = bg2
    }
}
```

what i see
full screen [full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAeX3.png)

also there are transitions between colors in rounded corners

[top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJj5D.png)

[bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FifE3.png)

Actually I don't want to see color changes (colour overlays) in the rounded corners.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: i added stroke for second gradient drawable
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPKGX.png) and i see that border color smoothed out.
i also try to add stroke for second (red color) view and positioned it directly above the first (blue color) view
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbN35.png)

I want something like that [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA3GA.png)
bottom bounds have the same coordinates, both views have the same rounding

Comment: You could try `setStroke` with the same color as the background to see if the stroke emphasizes the color on the corners

Comment: i updated answer with new screen with stroke for second drawable

Answer (score 0):

I could elaborate on this topic for hours, but in short: you want this effect. well, at least on top part of your view. and bottom doesn't look well, but you can add `layout_marginBottom` to it, right? homework: read about antialiasing

Comment: it is a sample project. In a real case i cant add layout_marginBottom. I need that behavior. same bottom border coordinates, same corner rounding. Actually i want to correct the bottom border

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint about antialiasing

Comment: when you achieve what you want you will notice that this looks bad, edges will be sharp and pixelised. way better is to introduce this margin, which make your static layout (like on screen) looking good. if you want to introduce e.g. some animation and bottom-layer-view will start be visible at some point (e.g. move to bottom) then in first frame of this anim just reset margin. good luck!